# Ph.D or not Ph.D?

Tags: phd, university, workplace

On october I get a master degrees of computer science. The thesis period is very full but I love it, because I learn every day new knowledge.

Now my fear is to finish and get a boring job. Yes, the world is full of opportunities, but in Italy I know a lot of people that have a repetitive job. 
I don't want to be offensive, and even arrogant, but I really love the university and the idea of do research.

This is the point, i want to do a Ph.d in computer science, but there is a problem: all people say me that in Italy is not required, and after Ph.D I risk to beacame a 30 years old jobless. Yes I can go in other country after Ph.D, but if I can't ? if i don't find opportunity with my Ph.D?

Even my professor tell me that in Italy there is not Job opportunity for Ph.D, there is no possibility to work in university after. Should I give up? suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give the job a chance.. I was thinking exactly like you when I finished my master in optical technologies. Maybe you are afraid of the new live (I mean as a worker). The job position has also many advantages. You will experience the feeling of deploying your knowledge it is really nice feeling. However, if you don't feel ok with job, you can apply for a Ph.D program carrying your experience in industry

Comment: The problem is that the mejority of new graduate become a generic java programmer. I have no problem with java but I don't want only type code. In seven months of this thesis I have already had to deal with Bayesin Network, Markov Chain Monte Carlo, Control Charts and every day I deal with new things. I doubt you can see so many things in seven month of working. In add I want to specialize in data analysis, only with only with Ph.D or with a company in this field i can do this. If I can't find a company in this field ready to hire me?